# Graph API - Groups - Add non friend user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbjs

My Facebook Canvas app has a closed Facebook group associated with it. I would like to auto add users who install the app to this closed group. The Facebook UI doesn't allow adding non friends to a group, is it possible via the API ? Also there doesn't seem to be any app permission associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably won't ever be a way to automatically add a user to a group.  Currently the Facebook [group api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) only allows you to view membership details.  Facebook may eventually allow you to invite users to the group using their group api.  On that documentation link in the comments, a Facebook employee named [Tiffany Chang Black](http://www.linkedin.com/in/tiffanycblack) comments that adding/removing users is not currently supported.